# I am getting an error while passing query string of url between two pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a project in which on first page that is default.aspx page I am having a grid view which is bind with a column *categoryname* of table *category*. Here is code default.aspx  :

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="catid"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="catid" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/subcategory.aspx?catid={0}"
                DataTextField="categoryname" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ToursandTravelsConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [catid], [categoryname] FROM [category]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

Now I am having a page named as subcategory.aspx which is having a label for subcategory name then its respective image and vice versa which is retrieved from table subcategory.Here is my code of subcategory.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    labelsubcatname.Text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["catid"]);      
}
```

The problem is that when I am having catid I am getting the value as 1,2 and so on but when I am having *subcatname* retrieved from table *subcategory* which is as follows :

[Image of table subcategory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nu3c.jpg)

Its does not  shows *subcatname* from *subcategory* table. How to get the value of subcategory instead of catid?

I also want to display the image based on subcategory name which I have showed up in a grid view. I am getting all images for now this is my code for its grid view

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="labelsubcatname" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="pic" SortExpression="pic">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pic") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="200px" 
                        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("pic") %>' Width="250px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="labelviewdetail" runat="server" Text="View Detail"></asp:Label>
    <br />
</td>

</table>
</div>
</form>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ToursandTravelsConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [pic] FROM [subcategory]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: If you pass the CategoryID in the query string you will have to run a query on the second page.

Comment: Can You tell me what query should i need to run on second page ? @SeanLange

Comment: A select statement to get the categoryname from your category table with a where clause of the value you passed in.

Comment: Should it be like this :  'Select subcatname from subcategory where catid=1 ' ? @SeanLange

Comment: Does that query return the value you want? Then I would say yes.

Comment: I dont think so can you tell me query what should i use ? @SeanLange

Comment: Do you know how to query a database? This is seriously like the most basic of things. You  pass in the catid you want right? You then need to query your database with the query you posted above except you use a parameter for the catid, not a hard coded 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inner join to your query in your DataSource so that you can get your subcatname from subcategory table, like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ToursandTravelsConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT C.[catid], C.[categoryname], S.[subcatname] FROM [category] C INNER JOIN subcategory S ON C.[catid] = S.[catid]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then use subcatname in your hyperlinkfield:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="subcatname" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/subcategory.aspx?subcatname={0}"
        DataTextField="categoryname" />
</Columns>
```

Then you can get it from the query string:

```
labelsubcatname.Text = Request.QueryString["subcatname"] != null
                        ? Request.QueryString["subcatname"].ToString()
                        : "N/A";
```

Comment: can i ask you silly question ? Should i apply the inner inner join in subcategory.aspx.cs file right ? @jomsk1e

Comment: You can update the query to your SqlDataSource1, see my update.

Comment: see my edit. What's the value of Request.QueryString["subcatname"] when you debug?

Comment: thank you bro it worked i have one more question edited in my post please do help me for it as well thank you :) @jomsk1e

Comment: I'm glad it helped! For the new question I think's that is irrelevant for this thread because the content of this thread is about passing query string on another page. That will be confusing to the future viewers of this thread. You should start a new question for that new question so different users can view and help you with.

Comment: Ok no problem  I ll post a new Question thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have your Subcatid in page load of subcategory.aspx. Then using Subcatid  to retrieve row value from database.

Comment: I am using subcatid instead of catid like this : ' labelsubcatname.Text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["subcatname"]);' but then I am not getting any output the label is left blank

Comment: Check solution above . I posted

Comment: thank you for your it got resolve please help me for one more questionmere i have edited my post please help thank you :) @Ricky007

Comment: No problem . Just like my post and what more questions you have ?

Comment: I have edit my post please go through it :) @Ricky007

Answer (score 0):

OK , Listen

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/subcategory.aspx?catid={0}"
```

means you are passing element 0 from data base i.e

Change it to 1 i.e

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/subcategory.aspx?catid={1}"
```

and you dont need

`HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["subcatname"]);'`

Just replace it by

Request.QueryString["subcatname"].ToString();

Comment: Try this DataNavigateUrlFields="subcatname"